# i have tried to make a contact submit form with nodejs nodemailer. Can I get it fixed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer

here is the server script, I have connected the HTML file to server using handlebars where the message is submitted.I'm using nodemailer to send mail which contains all the information in the form when it is submitted
server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.render('contact',{layout:false});
});

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
const output = `
<p>You have a new contact request</p>
<h3>Contact Details</h3>
<ul>  
  <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
  <li>Company: ${req.body.company}</li>
  <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
  <li>Phone: ${req.body.phone}</li>
</ul>
<h3>Message</h3>
<p>${req.body.message}</p> `;

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
 host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
  port: 587,
  secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
  auth: {
    user: 'franco10@ethereal.email',
    pass: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
  },
  tls:{
    rejectUnauthorized:false
  }
});

let mailOptions = {
     from: '"Nodemailer Contact" <your@email.com>', // sender address
     to: 'RECEIVEREMAILS', // list of receivers
     subject: 'Node Contact Request', // Subject line
     text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
     html: output // html body
    };


  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
     if (error) {
         return console.log(error);
     }
     console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);   
     console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

     res.render('contact', {msg:'Email has been sent'});
 });
 });

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started...'));
```

and here is the error I get after submitting the message in the contact form:

```
Error: No recipients defined
at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\Users\<user-name>\Desktop\sendEmail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:784:19)
at SMTPConnection._setEnvelope (C:\Users\<user-name\Desktop\sendEmail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:995:34)
at SMTPConnection.send (C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\sendEmail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:615:14)
at sendMessage (C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\sendEmail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-transport\index.js:227:28)
at C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\sendEmail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-transport\index.js:285:25
at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\sendEmail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1537:9)
at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\sendEmail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:550:26)
at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\sendEmail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:942:20)
at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\sendEmail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:749:14)
at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\sendEmail\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:195:44) {
code: 'EENVELOPE',
command: 'API'
}
```

contact.handlebars:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Acme Web Design</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" 
     rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384- 
     wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link rel="stylesheet" 
     href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/style.css">
  </head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <h1 class="brand"><span>Acme</span> Web Design</h1>
        <div class="wrapper animated bounceInLeft">
          <div class="company-info">
            <h3>Acme Web Design</h3>
              <ul>
                <li><i class="fa fa-road"></i> 44 Something st</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> (555) 555-5555</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> test@acme.test</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
              <div class="contact">
                 <h3>Email Us</h3>
                   {{msg}}
                <form method="POST" action="send">
                 <p>
                   <label>Name</label>
                   <input type="text" name="name">
                 </p>
                 <p>
                   <label>Company</label>
                   <input type="text" name="company">
                 </p>
                 <p>
                   <label>Email Address</label>
                   <input type="email" name="email">
                 </p>
                 <p>
                   <label>Phone Number</label>
                   <input type="text" name="phone">
                 </p>
                 <p class="full">
                   <label>Message</label>
                   <textarea name="message" rows="5"></textarea>
                 </p>
                 <p class="full">
                 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                 </p>
               </form>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
        </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: Its hard to diagnose the problem because you're using example strings in your code, but I would check the format of your `mailOptions.to` property to verify that your list of recipients is in a format that is compatible with the NodeMailer APi

Comment: thanks,I want it to get fixed. help me if possible

Comment: See if that works, and if not, I'd recommend editing your code and removing the necessary example text so your code is more elaborate